# How to cycle through data in LinkedHashMap on click

Tags: android

I'm trying to display some images as well as associated text but can't seem to figure out how to correctly cycle through them via a ImageButton onclick event.  All I'd like to do is go to next image each time button is clicked.  Once I reach the end, just start over.

Here's my code.  It's probably not the most elegant but it seems to work except that "currentid" somehow changes so I never find the current image in the foreach loop.

```
public class Fundamentals extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fundamentals);

    //Ojbects for forward and back buttons
    ImageButton forwardButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forward_button);

    //image object
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fundamentals_image);

    //Object for picture text
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fundamentals_text);

    //Images and associated text
    Map<Integer, String> fundamentalPics = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    fundamentalPics.put(R.drawable.fund1, "some interesting text");
    fundamentalPics.put(R.drawable.fund2, "more interesting text");
    fundamentalPics.put(R.drawable.fund3, "and more");

    //Set initial image
    Map.Entry<Integer,String> pic = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>) fundamentalPics.entrySet().iterator().next();
    imageview.setImageResource(pic.getKey());
    textview.setText(pic.getValue());

    imageview.setTag(fundamentalPics);
    }

    public void setImage(View v) {
    //Object for picture text
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fundamentals_text);

    //Object for picture image
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fundamentals_image);


    //get current id
    Integer currentid = imageview.getId();

    Map<Integer, String> fundamentalPics = (LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>) imageview.getTag();

    Boolean foundImage = false;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> pic : fundamentalPics.entrySet())
    {
        if (foundImage.equals(true)) {
            textview.setText(pic.getValue());
            imageview.setImageResource(pic.getKey());
            break;
        }
        //cycle until we find current image
        if (pic.getKey().equals(currentid)) {
            foundImage = true;

            if (!fundamentalPics.entrySet().iterator().hasNext()) {
                //we've reached the end.  go to beginning....
                Map.Entry<Integer,String> item = (Map.Entry<Integer, String>) fundamentalPics.entrySet().toArray()[0];
                textview.setText(item.getValue());
                imageview.setImageResource(item.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you keep that pic Object at instance level so you can access withing any call back method,instead of getting it from image.getTag.And also you can keep current image index on instance level ,it will simplifies the logic.Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing wrong :

```
if (pic.getKey().equals(currentid))
```

In your map, you stored drawable id, which is an id of image, so, getKey() will return drawable image's id and currentid has imageview's id which is defined in layout xml for that imageview (and not the image's drawable id). Although, both are integers, but consider the difference, one is from R.drawable.* and other is from R.id.*, one is each image's id and other is imageview's id.

So, imageview is the container in which images will get rendered, and you are comparing this container's id with the images ids, obviously, they won't match.

Unfortunately, there is no getDrawableId() for the imageview. A work around is to compare with every drawable id :

You can get the drawable like

```
Drawable myDrawable = imageview.getDrawable();
```

You can compare it with a drawable resource like :

```
if(imageview.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fund1) || imageview.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fund2) || imageview.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fund3)){
    //do work here
}
```

Of course, you can use better ways to compare, I just gave an example. Hope it helps !